# Inherit and add methods or compose new object and take data as argument?

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, beautifulsoup, architecture

I am self-learning object-oriented Python and have a classical "inherit or compose" question in my project. I read through many of the general guidelines/answers to this question, but it's hard for me to apply this to my specific case - so I decided to ask.

My program is a web-scraper, that's scrapes a website with different types of pages (and different data-objects from theses pages). I use BeautifulSoup (bs4) to parse the data from the raw request response. As there are many different data objects wanted, I need about 10 different parser-functions.

My question - what would be the best architecture for the parser-object?

A: Create a class 'mySoup' inheriting from BeautifulSoup and add the parser-functions as methods.

B: Create a class 'Parser' on its own, that takes the BeautifulSoup-object as argument.

I already changed back an forth between the two solutions and my personal feeling is, that I would rather pick the Inheritance-Solution, simply because it makes calling the parser clean and simple. Also 'Parser' doesn't look like a necessary object to me, more a collection of functions.

```
class mySoup(BeautifulSoup):
    def parseData1(self):
        data = self.find('foo', {'class':'bar'}).text
        return data

    def parseData2(self):
        ...
        return data

soup = mySoup(page_source)
data = soup.parseData1()
```

vs.

```
class Parser():
    def __init__(self,soup):
        self.soup=soup

    def parseData1(self):
        data = self.soup.find('foo', {'class':'bar'}).text
        return data

    def parseData2(self):
        ...
        return data

soup = BeautifulSoup(page_source)
data = Parser(soup).parseData1()
```

Comment: One `Soup` many `Parsers` - look up [`Strategy Pattern`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). Pass the appropriate `Parser` to the `Soup` object. You can consider inheritance for a `Parser` hierarchy, or simple `parser functions`.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the pattern I was looking for. I'll be able to google some implementations for python and see how I want to use it. Thank you!